# CSS div height won't expand

Tags: css, html

I have a sidebar DIV that i want to expand vertically to match its containing div.

I have done this to accomplish that

```
html, body, #wrapper, #content, #sidebar{
    height:100%;
}
```

But the wrapper, content, and sidebar never expand past about 1000px, even when the content is several times that.

I believe this is because the content of `#wrapper`, `#content` are entirely floated DIVs.

I have tried to put empty DIVs with `clear:both` as the last element in `#wrapper` and `#content`, but to no avail.

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="footer">
  </div>
  <div id="sidebar">
  </div>
  <div id="content">
   .... 
     <div class="clear"/>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"/>
</div>
</body>
```

note: footer is fixed position

Comment: .clear{clear:both}, if that helps

Comment: also, <div class="clear"/> was <div class="clear"></div> in code, but I copied and pasted from firebug

Comment: This may or may not help: http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/developing_with_web_standards/csslayout/2-col/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the problem is you set 100% to html, body, and #wrapper, this forces their height to be their parents' height, #wrapper's parent is body, body's is html, what's html's parent? I'm not sure, i'm guessing the browser window (or its view port), if so, then #wrapper's height will always be equal to the browser window's height, so if your browser window's height is 1000px, then 
`#wrapper`'s height will always be 1000px, and because you set 100% to #sidebar and #content, their height will always be 1000px as well, despite the height of inner elements

if i was right, what you should do is set html's height separately, keep others' height to 100%, and set html's min-height to 100% and leave the height out. in theory, this will force html to be at least as high as the browser window, but expand when inner elements are higher than the browser, though i haven't tested it.

let me know if i was right or not.

**Edit**:
<strike>I tested it, it works.
just do this:</strike>

```
html,
body{
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

don't set the height, and make sure clear the floats and no absolute positioning on inner elements if you want the inner elements' height to be taken into account. Now the body will occupy the whole view port of the browser window when there are not enough elements to push it, and when there are, the body will expand to the very bottom of the page, not just the browser window.

tested it in chrome and should work in firefox, too
don't know about ie.
no, actaully, on a second test, it failed to work
it seems only when the parent has a given height (eg. height: 500px or height: 100%), the height: 100% will work; when the parent element has min-height: 100% and no height, the inner element can not use height: 100% to match the parent.

Comment: interesting, i would think min-height would work, but on second thought, i guess it isn't really a set height.

Answer (score 4):

I can see no need to set height of those elements to 100%.
you are saying, "I have a sidebar DIV that i want to expand vertically to match its containing div." Do you mean you want the height of the sidebar to match the height of the #content DIV? In that case, consider "faux columns" method, described [here](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/). Another way would be to calculate the height of the #content div with Javascript, and applythat height to #sidebar.

To properly clear floats, the clearing element should be placed AFTER the floating element, not inside of it. One useful trick that I often use myself is pseudo-selector :AFTER. Suppose, you have to clear #content. Then:

```
#content:after
{
   content: ".";
   display:block;
   height:0;
   clear:both;
   visibility:hidden;
}
```

This will place an invisible element after your element, and it will clear your element.

Comment: faux columns might work, but thats kinda cheating, not that that's bad, but i would like to do it traditionally. The wrapper, content, and sidebar never expand past about 1000px (which is really the issue) so the JS thing wouldnt work. The sidebar IS the same height as #content, but they are both stunted for some reason.

Comment: oh, and for height:100%; to work, the parent must have a set height, so that is the reason behind that,

Answer (score 0):

To have a div match the height of its container, you can use positioning:

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
             "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
 <html>    
 <head>
 <style>
 #wrapper{position:absolute;top:0px;right:0px;bottom:0px;left:0px}
 #footer{position:absolute;height:100px;right:0px;bottom:0px;left:0px;background:green}
 #sidebar{position:absolute;width:200px;top:0px;bottom:100px;left:0px;background:blue}
 #content{position:absolute;top:0px;right:0px;bottom:100px;left:200px;background:red}
 </style>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div id="wrapper">
   <div id="footer">
   </div>
   <div id="sidebar">
   </div>
   <div id="content">
   </div>
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

from what I can tell its based on the `float:left/right` remove that and it will adjust